# PHP: Item displaying in the wrong place (Loop may not be working)

Tags: php, mysql

I am a newbie, I have created a products page, The products are broken down and displayed in their categories. At the bottom of each category their is a create new products form, on pressing add the products is inserted into the database and automatically displays on the webpage. (Created dynamically) This works perfectly.

[image]

My problem is for example if i try to add a new product into the "Burgers" category, the newly added product will show in the last category on the webpage. Instead of the category i am trying to add the new product too

I am confused to why this is happening. I am using a looped string which is echo'd out of a DB To create all the information on the page.
Below is the code i am using to generate the products and categories.

**Categories**

```
$REST_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_SESSION['Resturant_ID']);
$fc_sel = $dbc->query("SELECT * FROM Food_Cat WHERE Resturant_ID ='$REST_id'");
$fc_sel->data_seek(0);

$i = 1;

while ($fc_output = $fc_sel->fetch_assoc()) {
    $fc_run .= $fc_output['Food_Cat_name'] . $fc_output['Food_Cat_Desc'] . '<br>';
    $_SESSION['Food_Cat_name'] = $fc_output['Food_Cat_name']; //echo out product name
    $_SESSION['Food_Cat_Desc'] = $fc_output['Food_Cat_Desc']; //echo out product desc
    $_SESSION['Food_Cat_ID'] = $fc_output['Food_Cat_ID']; //echo out product desc

    echo("<form name='first_prod' id='first_prod$i' enctype='multipart/form-data' action='Restaurant_Menu.php' method='POST' accept-charset='utf-8'>");

    echo("<div id='input'>");
    echo("<input type='text' id='cat_name$i' name='cat_name' class='centre_inp' value='" . $_SESSION['Food_Cat_name'] . " '  placeholder='Category name'>");
    echo("<br>");
    echo("<input type='text' id='cat_desc$i' name='cat_desc' value='" . $_SESSION['Food_Cat_Desc'] . " ' class='centre_inp'  placeholder='Description'>");
    echo("</div>");

    echo("<br>");
    echo("<div id='buts'>");
    echo("<input type='submit' id='submit_addon$i' name='submit_addon' value='Submit'>");
    echo("<input type='button' id='delete_addon$i' name='delete_addon' value='delete'>");
    echo("</div>");

    echo("<br>");


    echo("<hr id='dotted'>");
    echo("<br>");

    // ADD NEW ITEM TOGGLE
    echo("<p >Menu Item</p>");
```

**Products**

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_INDEX);
$rest_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_SESSION['Resturant_ID']);
$fc_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_SESSION['Food_Cat_ID']);
$fc_p_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$_SESSION['Product_Id']);
$prod_sel = $dbc->query("SELECT * FROM Product WHERE  Food_Cat_ID ='$fc_id' AND Resturant_ID ='$rest_id'");
$prod_sel->data_seek(0);

$ii = 1;

while ($output = $prod_sel->fetch_assoc()) {
    $prod_run .= $output['Product_Name'] . $output['Product_Desc'] . $output['Product_Price'] . '<br>';
    $_SESSION['Product_Name'] = $output['Product_Name']; //echo out product name
    $_SESSION['Product_Desc'] = $output['Product_Desc']; //echo out product desc
    $_SESSION['Product_Price'] = $output['Product_Price']; //echo out price

    echo("<div id='nu_it'>");
    echo("<div id='nu_head_name' onclick='toggle_visibility(\"nu_show$ii\")'>");
    echo("<p id='products_name'>" . $_SESSION['Product_Name'] . "</p>");
    echo("</div>");
    echo("<div id='nu_show$ii' class ='hidden'>");
    echo("<br>");
    echo("<input type='text' id='item_name$ii' name='item_name' value='" . $_SESSION['Product_Name'] . "'>");
    echo("<br>");
    echo("<textarea id='desc$ii' name='desc' placeholder='Item description' rows='4' maxlength='200'required >" . $_SESSION['Product_Desc'] . " </textarea>");
    echo("<br>");
    echo("<input type='text' id='price' name='price' value='" . $_SESSION['Product_Price'] . "'>");
    echo("<input type='submit' id='add_item' name='add_item' value=''>");
    $ii++;
    echo("</div>");
    echo("</div>");
}
```

**Add new item (as requested)**

```
     if (isset($_POST['add_item'])) {
        $item_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['item_name']);
        $desc = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['desc']);
        $price = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['price']);
        $rest_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_SESSION['Resturant_ID']);
        $fc_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_SESSION['Food_Cat_ID']);
        if ($rest_id < 1) {
            $rest_id = 456;
        }
        // price validate - must be decimal(float)
        if (empty($_POST['price']) || !filter_var($_POST['price'], FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT) || ($_POST['price'] <= 0)) {
            $add_product_errors['price'] = "Please enter a product price";
        }
        // item name validate
        if (empty($_POST['item_name'])) {
            $add_product_errors['item_name'] = "Please enter a name";
        }
        // item name description
        if (empty($_POST['desc'])) {
            $add_product_errors['desc'] = "Please enter a product description";
        }

        $query = "INSERT INTO Product(Resturant_ID, Product_Name,Product_Desc,Product_Price,Food_Cat_ID) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)
         ON DUPLICATE KEY 
         UPDATE
    Resturant_ID = ?
    ,Product_Name = ?
    ,Product_Desc = ?
    ,Product_Price = ?
    ,Food_Cat_ID = ?"; //on duplicate input update row
        //var_dump($databaseObject);
        $run_query = $databaseObject->prepare($query);

        $run_query->bind_param('issdiissdi', $rest_id, $item_name, $desc, $price, $fc_id, $rest_id, $item_name, $desc, $price, $fc_id);
        // THIS now executes the above transaction, returns TRUE if successful - issdissd duplicate update
        if (!$run_query->execute()) {
            $insertError = "There was an error inserting data: " . $run_query->error;
        }

        print "affected rows:" . $run_query->affected_rows; //how many records affected? 
        $run_query->free_result(); // Frees memory on completion 
        $run_query->close(); //closes this action 
    }
```

**What i have done**

- started a session
- I have error handlers
- Select query that print sessions

I have tried to only supply the correct and smallest amount of text.

Comment: I don't see the "Add new item" button in your code.

Comment: We can see you are a noob across your code. Try to follow this rule. Never ever mix php with html with millions of echos... create your html with div and ids. Use javascript and jquery to manipulate it. Use ajax to query php , one echo, use the returned php values to manipulate your html... right now your code is a mess.

Comment: The basic problem is that you're overwriting the session variables each time through the loop. If you use the session variables when doing the `INSERT` query, it will always use the last items. You need to send the category ID in a hidden field in the form, and use that when updating the database.

Comment: @Barmar so sorry. I didn't add that , wasn't sure if it was needed. I will add now

Comment: That's the part that's not working, of course it's needed!

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) if you ever forget to properly escape something.

Comment: @Barmar i thought it was within the loop that the problem was occurring, Okay so i should make a hidden form field and call that within my query. I have done that previously but was advised it was a bad practice

Comment: @tadman thank you. I will have a read of the link and apply this

Comment: I'm a little confused about your post since you said `products is inserted into the database and automatically displays on the webpage. (Created dynamically) This works perfectly` but proceeded to say that it is displayed in the wrong category. Is it correctly inserted into the database with the correct category, and the problem is only with the display?

Comment: @Rickkwa sorry, i did try to be as clear as possible. What it does is it inserts and displays but with the wrong category. The product will be inserted into one category but display in another(the last category on the page)

Comment: @Monroe No problem. Can you confirm that it the inserted product has the  correct `Food_Cat_ID` in the database? Also, you mentioned that the display is created dynamically; is there code for this that you can show?

Comment: @Rickkwa In the database the inserted product is not assigned to the Food_Cat_ID it is inserted under. it is assigned to the Food_Cat_ID it is displayed under. The code has been provided (sorry may have used the wrong term) under the products heading

Answer (score 1):

Use the dropdown for showing categories to select from instead of input, and set the select option value equal to the category ID and text as category name.

For example:

```
<select name="Food_Cat_ID">
  <option value="category id goes here">Category name goes here</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Just trying to get my head around this. So you are suggesting to delete the form and add a drop dow instead